# Won't override /Fd flag using set_property and COMPILE_PDB_NAME

Tags: cmake

I changed cmake versions and now it now seems the release .pdb file is always called "vc100.pdb".

I want to change that name, overriding the `/Fd` flag for `cl.exe`

Changing CMakeLists.txt, this works: `add_compile_options("/FdRelease/<name>.pdb")`

This does nothing: `set_property(SOURCE PROPERTY COMPILE_PDB_NAME <name>.pdb)`

It seems to me like the second option is the official one, but I can't get it to work, file is still called "vc100.pdb".
Why is it not working? Is there anything I need to consider (eg. a gotcha) if I decide for the first approach?

Windows 10 64bit, cmake 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `set_property(TARGET <target> PROPERTY COMPILE_PDB_NAME <target_name>)` at the end of `CMakeLists.txt`